# How to prove that if a group has no proper subgroup it is finite

Tags: group-theory

How to prove that if a group has no proper subgroup it is finite.
Need some hint.

Comment: If the group isn't trivial, consider the subgroup generated by any $a \neq 1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: Take a non-identity element $x\in G$. Consider the group generated by $x$ - two cases arise. In one case consider also the group generated by $x^2$.

---

To fill out the case where the order of $x$ is infinite - to avoid the long discussion below - consider the group generated by $x^2$. If this is not a proper subgroup, it must be the whole group, and therefore the group generated by $x^2$ must contain $x$. We therefore have an integer $k$ with $(x^2)^k=x^{2k}=x$

If $k=0$ we have $x=1$ (using $1$ for the group identity). If $k\gt 0$ we have $x^{2k-1}=1$, and if $k\lt 0$ we have $x^{1-2k}=1$ - in each case contrary to the initial assumption that $x$ had infinite order.

This also establishes (by contradiction) that in the infinite cyclic group generated by $x$, $x^2$ generates a proper subgroup [obviously now assuming $x$ does not have finite order]. This is a result quoted in the comments below.

Comment: if we consider x to of infinite order, then $x^2$ generates a proper subgroup of $G$. Why is that so?

Comment: @AmanMittal - suppose $x$ is in the subgroup generated by $x^2$ - what does that mean?

Comment: It means that all the elements of $x$ can be written as some integral power of $x^2$ [if $x$ is the generated subgroup]

Comment: @AmanMittal it specifically means $x=x^{2k}$ for some integer $k$ ...

Comment: yes, but how can we say that $x^2$ generates a $proper$ subgroup of $G$ ?

Comment: @AmanMittal You are looking in the wrong place, you don't need to consider the subgroup - when we started considering $x^2$, what fact did we know about $x$?

Comment: $x$ is infinite. I am confused now. I just found a proof in a book which considers $x$ to be infinite and then says that $x$ infinite implies that $x^2$ generates a proper subgroup, but which is not true and hence $x$ must be of finite order. I donot understand how it implies that $x^2$ generates a proper subgroup....$x$ generates $G$

Comment: I have extended the answer rather than the discussion

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful !